# Speed up finding IDs in xml by indexing?

Tags: python, xml, performance, search, lxml

I have `.xml` files that are 70 - 100MB in size that I need in a Python based project. I use the same file for most of the time to look up stuff for a new task. My work involves a lot of jumping for reference ids. Right now I use the python lib "lxml" for the parsing and finding of elements. I'm completely satisfied with the speed of parsing and finding of my "random" and "unknown" elements.

The random elements often contain several ref links to other elements. My way of finding them is

```
new_el = etree.xpath(f"//*[@id = '{ref}']", )[0]
```

This takes about 0.5sec and makes my use case slow.

To speed up the process, I thought about pickling all the ref id´s, turns out the etree elements cant be pickled, and also the size increase would not be desirable. Next thought that came to mind was saving the ***id_element.sourceline***  attribute in a dict together with the id spending some time on one single run indexing the `.xml` file. Sadly, I found no way of using the sourceline (start line of the found element) as an "offset" for the `.find()` / `.findall()` / `.xpath()` functions.

Any thought or hints on how to improve my situation?
Would a "line offset" feature be a nice improvement for the lxml package?

Comment: Parsing the XML files into Python data structures once at the beginning of your code would probably be the simplest solution (and while doing this you can build a simple id-to-element dictionary).

Comment: The elements have an index access to their sub elements like "etree.getroot()[2][1][0]" which should be faster. You could once recursively search the tree and store these "number paths" to the elements with an id.

Comment: If you use an etree that means you have already parsed the entire XML document, correct? In that case why not scan it once for all objects that have ID attributes and put references to their nodes into a dictionary?

Comment: Thx for all the replies, I ended up using Michaels proposal and "maped" my way back to the root like this:        
id_obj = self.tree.xpath(
            f"//*[@id = '{ref}']",
        )[0]
id_obj_trak = []
while True:
    parent = id_obj.getparent()
    if parent:
         idx = parent.index(id_obj)
         id_obj_trak.append(idx)
         id_obj = parent
     else:
          break